# C++ producer-consumer using blocking buffer

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm working on a programming exercise (university, nothing related to industry) which basically asks to implement a Buffer to be used by two threads (a producer and a consumer). The first one enqueues data calling `next(T t)`, while the other gets the oldest value (in a FIFO mechanism) calling `consume()` or waits if the buffer is empty. The producer can send a stop signal to declare the enqueuing ended. The text also requires a `fail()` method in case anything goes wrong, but I'd like to ignore it for this question.
This is my solution

```
template <typename T>
class Buffer {
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::queue<T> values;
    bool stop, failed;
    std::exception_ptr _eptr;

public:
    Buffer() : stop(false), failed(false) {}

    void fail (const std::exception_ptr &eptr){
        { 
          std::unique_lock ul{m};
          failed = true;
          _eptr = eptr;
        }
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void terminate(){
        {
          std::unique_lock ul {m};
          if (stop || failed ) throw std::runtime_error("enqueing has stopped");
          stop = true;
        }
        cv.notify_one(); // notify stop signal
    }

    void next(T t) {
        {
        std::unique_lock ul{m};
        if ( stop || failed ) throw std::runtime_error ("enqueing has stopped");
        values.push(t);
        }
        cv.notify_one(); // notify the consumer (if waiting)
    }

    std::optional<T> consume(){
        std::unique_lock ul{m};
        cv.wait(ul, [this]() { return !values.empty() || stop || failed; });
        if (values.empty()) { // if got notified and the queue is empty, then stop or failed have been sent
            if (stop)
                return std::nullopt;
            else
                std::rethrow_exception(_eptr);
        }
        // extract the value to consume
        T val = values.front();
        values.pop();
        return std::optional<T>(val);
    }
};
```

This is how I think the Buffer might be used (I'm still ignoring the `fail()` method)

```
#define N 10000

  Buffer<int> buf;

    std::thread prod([&buf](){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N; ++i) {
            std::cout << "enqueing: " << i << std::endl;
            buf.next(i);
        }

        buf.terminate();
    });

    std::thread cons([&buf](){
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            std::cout << "consuming: " << buf.consume().value() << std::endl;
    });

    prod.join();
    cons.join();
```

I got some questions:

- do you agree this is nothing but a blocking queue or am I missing something ?
- do I need to implement the destructor ? If it is the case, can you please show me an example of usage that requires having it?
- What happens if the object goes out of scope and nobody called `terminate()` ? Should I take care of this problem ? Is it anyway a `Buffer` 's problem or the programmer using this class should care about it ? Can you please show me an example when this happens (I was thinking  about the threads being detached instead of joined, does it fit ?) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. Looks like a queue. Maybe all multithreading is really a queue? ...  *strokes beard philosophically*

---

Naming:

- `terminate()` should probably be called `finished()` or `done()` or something similar. (To distance it from `std::terminate`). `stop()` would also be wrong, since that implies we're telling the threads to stop processing regardless of whether there's more input. What we're really saying is simply that there's no more input to process.
- `next()` should be called `push()`... because that's what it does.
- `consume()` would be better named something like `wait_and_pop()`.

---

```
void terminate(){
    {
      std::unique_lock ul {m};
      if (stop || failed ) throw std::runtime_error("enqueing has stopped");
      stop = true;
    }
    cv.notify_one(); // notify stop signal
}
```

I don't think we need to throw an error if the queue is already stopped (or failed). We can just do nothing and return. (Similar to calling close on a file that's already closed. It's not wrong, there's just nothing to do). Especially since we have no way to check if the queue is currently stopped!

(It might be worth adding an `bool is_stopped() const`. Note that making this function `const` would mean making the mutex a `mutable` variable (which is fine)).

We should call `notify_all` instead of notify one. We presumably want all threads to stop waiting promptly.

We could use `std::lock_guard` instead of `std::unique_lock` (we don't need any of the extra functionality of `std::unique_lock`).

---

```
void next(T t) {
    {
    std::unique_lock ul{m};
    if ( stop || failed ) throw std::runtime_error ("enqueing has stopped");
    values.push(t);
    }
    cv.notify_one(); // notify the consumer (if waiting)
}
```

We could use `std::move` when pushing the value onto the queue: `values.push(std::move(t));`.

Again, we could use `std::lock_guard` instead of `std::unique_lock`.

---

```
std::optional<T> consume(){
    std::unique_lock ul{m};
    cv.wait(ul, [this]() { return !values.empty() || stop || failed; });
    if (values.empty()) { // if got notified and the queue is empty, then stop or failed have been sent
        if (stop)
            return std::nullopt;
        else
            std::rethrow_exception(_eptr);
    }
    // extract the value to consume
    T val = values.front();
    values.pop();
    return std::optional<T>(val);
}
```

Here we do need `std::unique_lock`. :)

Again we can do `T val = std::move(values.front());`

I'm not sure the logic here is quite correct. If the `failed` flag is set, we probably need to do something about it even if the queue *isn't* empty? (I don't know what your spec says though).

---

Destruction:

Yep, we need a destructor. It's quite possible for the `Buffer` to be destroyed while consumer threads are still trying to read from it. A contrived example:

```
auto consumers = std::vector<std::thread>();

{
    auto buf = Buffer<int>();

    for (auto i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
        consumers.emplace_back([&] () { while (true) { auto value = buf.consume(); if (!value) return; std::cout << value.value(); } });

    for (auto i = 0; i != 5000; ++i)
        buf.next(i);
    
    buf.terminate();

} // buf goes out of scope here! but we don't know that consumers have finished consuming!

for (auto& c : consumers)
    c.join();
```

We have two choices:

- Make this an obvious programming error (print an error message to `std::cerr` and call `std::terminate` if necessary (when `failed` isn't set, or when `stop` is set, but the queue isn't empty).
- Make it less dangerous (assume that input is finished and we want to finish processing it, so set `stop` in the destructor and then wait for the queue to be empty).

I think the second option is better - depending on whether threads have finished work as an error condition may end up calling `std::terminate` quite randomly.

Comment: I don't get why using your example, the program exits with 0 and the expected output even if the buffer went out of scope.
Notice: I replaced the `while(true)` with a `for` iterating N tiems and I only introduced 1 consumer and 1 producer.

Comment: It's undefined behavior, so it might work, or it might not. Maybe the consumer finished quickly, maybe the consumer is still accessing memory that has the right values in it even though the buffer is destroyed... etc.

Comment: You should probably get in the habit of using `scoped_lock`, rather than `lock_guard`. It *usually* doesn’t make a difference, but when it does, it *really* does. So why have yet another special case? Why create the problem of having to explain when to use one or the other? Just “forget” `lock_guard`—remember it as yet another failed experiment, like `auto_ptr`, that ultimately became obsolete by new and better technologies—and now the only rule you need to remember is “just do `auto lock 
= std::scoped_lock{mutex}`”.

Comment: @indi. I guess. I'm just following the advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60172828